# How to find the password stored in django.contrib.auth.models.User

Tags: django

I want to check what is the password I stored in the DB for the user named as 'user'.

Here is what I have done.

```
user@ubuntu:~/Documents/Django/django_bookmarks$ python manage.py shell
Python 2.7.1+ (r271:86832, Apr 11 2011, 18:05:24) 
[GCC 4.5.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> user = User.objects.get(id=1)
>>> user.username, user.password
(u'user', u'sha1$6934a$f92c73726c0bd5d4821013ad4161578a2114090f')
>>> 
>>> import hashlib
>>> hexhash = hashlib.sha1("password")
>>> hexhash
<sha1 HASH object @ 0x99c18c0>
>>> hexhash.digest
<built-in method digest of _hashlib.HASH object at 0x99c18c0>
```

I remember that I have used 'password' for the password of user but I cannot verify it.

Question> How can I find out what the password for the user is?

Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check the user's password with `check_password`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.check_password

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

user = User.objects.get(id=1)
user.check_password('password') # Returns True or False
```

Answer (score 2):

django has been hashed your passwd, this is a function that only works in a way.

You can try to search the sha1 on a [hash database](http://www.hash-database.net/), but they are not guaranty to found it.

You should search for 'f92c73726c0bd5d4821013ad4161578a2114090f'. Hash function is sha1 and key used to hash is '6934a'

Answer (score 1):

You can not get the actual password that you have set. set_password method converts original password into sha1 code. 
You can only check your password, either this is correct or not.

also check this link

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.check_password